# Broken Promoted Links in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, promoted-links

I’m having some problems posting Promoted Links inside a site (Portal Site) asking for pages in other sites (Publishing Sites). We have a news mecanism incorporated in my company, we’ve created a specific site for company’s news and we would like to use those pages inside the Promoted Links open dialogs.
Have you seen something like this before? In those cases fails irremediably. But, here goes the curiosity, external links (Internet or even Local Site Links or Pages are viewed).
Preciate help.
Thanks.